# Option value wont update MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I'm trying to update an existing row in the table cms_events. But my option value wont trigger the column "code". The option values is listed, but have no effect after saving. Any suggestions? best regards

```
<select class="form-control" name="code" style="width:65%;">

<?php
    $code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
        $stripped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        if(isset($_POST['event']))
        {
                        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_events SET code = '$code', userid = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'
                            WHERE id = $stripped

                            ")
                        or die(mysql_error());

                                header('Location: /index.php?url=events&id='.htmlspecialchars($stripped).'&code='.htmlspecialchars($code).'');
                        exit;

                }

 $getKommentar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cms_prosjekt` WHERE userid = '".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user']['id'])."'");
                        while($kommentarinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getKommentar)) 

                {

                        echo'<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($kommentarinfo['code']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($kommentarinfo['code']).'</option>';

                                }

}
?>

</select>
```

Comment: show your update function code how save form value

Comment: <form action="" method="post" style="width:100%;">
<button type="submit" name="event" class="btn btn-blue" style="background-color:#1c76ba; color:white;">Oppdater kurset</button></form> @razibalmamun

Comment: where `<select class="form-control" name="code" style="width:65%;">` tag  in your `<form></form>`

Comment: You're writing with dead `mysql_*` extension..